# AndroidX incompatibilities issue arises in my Flutter project while run my flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, androidx

I am getting the AndroidX incompatibility issue in my flutter project even I have migrated my flutter project to AndroidX. and still getting the same issue again.
I have followed the flutter documentation to migrate in AndroidX Here I have shared the link of documentation 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

please help me out. I have spent so many hours still not getting any solution.
Thanks in Advance.

the error I am getting is below

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://gradle.org/help/

BUILD FAILED in 44s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: For me, all I did was adding `android.useAndroidX=true` and 
`android.enableJetifier=true` to `android/gradle.properties`

Comment: It's already true for me `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` in my flutter  `android/gradle.properties`. and still getting same error

Comment: Some packages need newer gradle version. you can use their earlier version or just upgrade your gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

What is your gradle version in App/build.gradle? this erro possibly has been caused beacause your gradle version is 3.2.1, some packages need gladle 3.3.x or above to work properly